# What is the geometrical meaning or implications of making variable substitution?

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic-geometry

Let $x,y,z$ be real numbers and $$F(x,y,z)=ax^3+bx^3+cy^3+dx^2y+ex^2z+fxy^2+gxz^2+hy^2z+iyz^2+jxyz+k$$ $(a,b,c,\cdots$ are nonzero integers)

If I write $z=rx+sy$ where $r,s$ are real numbers and substitute $z$ in $F$, I will obtain a bivariate polynomial of degree 3 with real coefficients. I am curious to know the  geometrical implication  of such variable change? Is this a projection of the curve F on a 2-dimensional plane? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize if my wording is confusing. What I am trying to wrap my head around is: if i plot F(x,y,z) I will certainly obtain a curve of space. If I write $z$ as linear combination of $x$ and $y$, why is the plot will be like? In mathematical terms, what did I do? I hope this is a little clearer. Thanks

Comment: I want to know what how different the curves are with 2 and 3 coordinates. How do you call that process in mathematics? Thanks for the reference.

Comment: I am not trying to solve an equation. I just want to know what happens geometrically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be helpful to first consider a lower dimensional example.
Suppose $\,F(x,y)\,$ is a real valued function of two real variables.
Then the equation $\,z=F(x,y)\,$ is a surface in three space.
If we make a substitution such as $\,y=rx+s,\,$ now $\,z=F(x,y)\,$
is a curve in three space which is a **slice** of the original surface.
That is, we find the intersection of the surface with a plane whose
result is a curve embedded in three space.

In your example of $\,F(x,y,z)\,$ and substitution $\, z=rx+sy,\,$ a very similar process happens. The equation $\,w=F(x,y,z)\,$ is a hypersurface in four space. After
the substitution we get the intersection of the hypersurface with a hyperplane. The
result is a two dimensional surface embedded in four space.